# How to skip one or more cells when pasting content into an Excel by using Openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, text, row, highlight

I'm trying paste texts into a column of an existing excel. However, I need to skip all the highlighted cells. For example:

**content.txt**
1
2
3
4
5

**workbook.xlsx** should look like
 
[image]

Below are the codes I have so far:

```
import os, openpyxl
f = open("content.txt", mode="r+")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'workbook.xlsx')
worksheet = wb.active

r = 1
for line in f.readlines():
    if worksheet.cell(row=r, column=9).fill.bgColor.value != '00000000':
        r+=1
        worksheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value = line
        r+=1
        continue
    else:
        worksheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value = line
        r += 1
f.close()
```

But it only skips one highlighted row..I'm still trying to figure it out though.

Or if I write the code like this:

```
import os, openpyxl
f = open("content.txt", mode="r+")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'workbook.xlsx')
worksheet = wb.active

r = 1
for line in f.readlines():
    if worksheet.cell(row=r, column=9).fill.bgColor.value != '00000000':
       r+=1
       continue
    else:
        worksheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value = line
    r += 1
f.close()
```

The result would be:
[image]
(The txt `line` are also skipped...)

Let me know if you have any ideas. Should i use a while loop...? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Add an `if` statement inside your `for` loop

```
r = 1
for line in f.readlines():
    if worksheet.cell(row=r, column=1).fill.bgColor.value != '00000000':
    # '00000000' corresponds to no fill
       continue
    worksheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value = line
    r += 1
f.close()
```

Also the indent is missing for `r+=1` in the code you've posted here.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I'm looking for. I'm actually dealing with a more complicated excel and won't know exactly which row has the highlight.

Comment: Alright, It was not clear that a random row could be highlighted within the excel input sheet. Could you please tell me if the highlight color remains the same.? Green in your case.?

Comment: HI @Ash Sharma, thank you for updating your answer! I didn't try it until today. But after test the code, it still didn't work as expected. The content stopped to be pasted at the highlighted cell. (screenshot: http://i.prntscr.com/gdFoJ4vWTCyjZrVE09dr4Q.png)

Comment: Here's the updated code, by the way: http://i.prntscr.com/hdIMLI8KRVC8OdzcLsX9jA.png

Answer (score 1):

OK I got the answer with the help of @Ash Sharma!

This code works for me:

```
import os, openpyxl
f = open("content.txt", mode="r+")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'workbook.xlsx')
worksheet = wb.active

r = 1
for line in f.readlines():
    if worksheet.cell(row=r, column=1).fill.bgColor.value != '00000000':
    # '00000000' corresponds to no fill
       r+=1
       worksheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value = line
       r+=1
       continue
    else:
        worksheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value = line
        r += 1

f.close()

wb.save('test_Result.xlsx')
```